# Apache игнорирует .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Неважно, что находится в `.htaccess`, например пробовал туда написать

```
blablabla
```

что должно выдавать на любой запрос к серверу ошибку `500`, но все страницы успешно открываются с полным игнорированием `.htaccess`.

Владелец файла `www-data`, группа та же, права доступа `700`.

В `apache2.conf` в наличии

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Apache перезапускал. Заодно всю VM.

В логе ошибок и доступа Apache ничего нет по проблеме.

Что это может быть?
Появилось после обновления VM до Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настройках виртуального хоста `стояло

```
AllowOverride None
```

что весьма странно, потому что до обновления Ubuntu 12.04 -> 14.04 там было положенное:

```
AllowOverride All
```